# SQL error 22008 with INSERT INTO

Tags: android, sql-server

Hello  I try to insert  in sql

My code is:

```
    archivo = new File("file name");
            fr = new FileReader(archivo);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            select = connection.createStatement();
            statement = "INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES (";
            cantidad = 0;
            while(br.readLine() != null)
            {
                cantidad++;
            }
            br.close();
            fr = new FileReader(archivo);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            contador=0;
            while((linea = br.readLine())!= null)
            {
                 arrayString = linea.split("\\|");
                 for(int i = 0; i < arrayString.length; i++)
                 {
                     statement = statement + "'" + arrayString[i] + "',";
                 }
                 statement = statement.substring(0, statement.length() - 1) + ");";



                 select.executeUpdate(statement);
```

at the end before of select.executeUpdate(statement)

```
    statement = INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('mx','mz','11','43','0','0','0','0','0','2015-01-19 09:24:20','0','10737','2015-01-19 09:24:20','20.71878','-103.45705','N','W','0.0','T','s','0.0','0.0','0.0','0.0','0.0','0.0','0.0','0.0','0.0','0.0','0.0','0.0','0.0','0.0','0.0','0.0','0.0','0.0','J1939','21','56','124','0','0','0');
```

then i receive the error SQL 22008

What is wrong?

Regards

Comment: At the very least, show us your DDL.

Comment: ok... so you get the solution ... but seriously, are you calling this code from android device? (if no, why it has an adroid tag?)

Comment: Yes, I've got the solution.... And Yes I'm calling this code in android device.@323go

And what you mean with DDL?  I'm new.@Selvin

Note: Sorry if my english isn't good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DateTime field format you have chosen is not acceptable.

```
2015-01-19 09:24:20
```

Try to convert to something like:

```
2015-01-19T09:24:20
```

Source on more formats:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is inserting some sort of tab or line break in the middle of your timestamps that you are trying to insert, that is making SQL Server throw an error that it didn't understand your format and tried to truncate/round the datetime value.

Try changing your code such that your datetime value are in the following format:

yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss

For example:
2015-01-19T09:43:35